# May I volunteer while visiting for 3 months in The Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, visa-free-entry, volunteering, colombian-citizens

I am going to visit The Netherlands for les than 90 days (time allowed to stay there) without visa for Colombian people. I would like to learn about the culture and language volunteering without being paid since I don't have a work permit. Is it possible?

Comment: depends on the nature of the "volunteering"